# Using an image instead of a colored rectangle

Tags: java, tiles

I recently watched a video on how to do tilemaps in java. He has the tiles as colored rectangles. I want them to be images.

My code:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    for(int row = 0; row < mapheight; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < mapwidth; col++){

             int rc = map[row][col];

             if(rc == 0){
                 g.setColor(Color.green);
             }

             if(rc == 1){
                 g.setColor(Color.yellow);
             }


             g.fillRect(x + col * tilesize, y + row * tilesize,tilesize,tilesize);


        }
    }
}
```

This is the tilemap class.
It says if rc is = to 0 it sets the color to green. Is there any way I can change that to an image?

Answer (score 1):

Without a fairly substantial change in your code, your options are limited.

If you take a look at the functions provided for you in the [`Graphics` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), you'll find a [`drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) function that will allow you to draw an image instead of using the existing [`fillRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function.

Even this simpler change is going to require more changes to your code than just one line. You'll need to add image loading, storage and selection.

I recommend you find a tutorial for tile maps using images, instead of attempting to modify this code to work for you.